# How to return a String to onCreate from GetDataTask

Tags: java, android

I have written a `GetDataTask()` class that takes in a `String` which is a URL.  The `doInBackGround()` method reads in some text with a `StringBuilder` object and returns it as a `String` to the `onPostExecute()`.  At least that is where I think it is being send.

In `onCreate()`, I am call this by using:

```
 new GetDataTask().execute(URL);
```

How can I get the `String` that is created in `GetDataTask()` back to `onCreate()`
If more code is needed, I can provide it.  I just figure this is the normal standard way to do this so I didn't see the need to copy a bunch of code.

Thanks to anyone looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get result from AsyncTask using its get method

```
new GetDataTask().execute(URL).get();
```

To get the result make your asynctask task return type as String if you want String result

Comment: you can simply get the result using this..you don't have to do much..just set the return type

Comment: This certainly works also! And only one line of code.  Well and the try catch around it.

Comment: @WeVie just so you know, this is waiting for the result to arrive and blocks your UI thread so if you are getting a lot of data or have a slow internet connection the app will freeze until you get the data

Answer (score 2):

Your main question is:

> How can I get the String that is created in GetDataTask() back to onCreate()

Now this can be understood in two ways.

#### 1) You want to store this `String` so that next time `onCreate()` is called you have access to it. This can be done the following way:

You can, for example, store the result in a `Bundle` that you gets passed to `onCreate()` method when it's called. The `Bundle` is standardly called `savedInstanceState` and you can do it like this:

```
class YOUR_CLASS extends Activity { // or whatever else :)

// ...
String string_you_need = null;
// ...

class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,String>{

    // ...

    protected Void doInBackground(URL... url) {
        // ... 
    }

    // ...

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
       string_you_need = result;
    }
}

// ...
```

Save the string in the `Bundle`:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putString("ID_FOR_STRING_I_NEED", string_you_need);
}

// ...
```

Then when your `onCreate()` gets called, you can access what you stored here using the ID you choose:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
     String STORED_STRING =  savedInstanceState .getString("ID_FOR_STRING_I_NEED");
  }
}
```

You can also use something called [**`SharedPreferences`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for the same effect.

#### 2) You want to return this `String` so that next statement in `onCreate()` after `new GetDataTask().execute(URL);` will have access to that `String`.

Unfortunately, this can't be done (at least not nicely) because you are using an **ASYNCHRONOUS** task which means we cannot synchronize with it, the time it takes to do its stuff cannot be determined and known ahead Asynchronous code doesn't flow sequentially, it reacts by triggers. That's why you have methods like `onPostExecute` that get called **after a task is finished** but when will the task finish is unknown. Therefore, by the time you obtain your results, the `onCreate()` might already be finished executing.

As @Vang suggested, one way to do this is to block your main thread while data isn't obtained but that isn't very useful and you definitely don't want to do this

You can still use the example above to store the results right away instead of storing for the next call to `onCreate()`. Look at the `string_you_need` variable. It stores your results as soon as you receive them. However, this way gives access to your result **As soon as AsyncTask is finished** so `onCreate()` might finish by then as well.

If you tell me why you need to return a `String` to `onCreate()` and show more relevant code sections maybe I can give you an advice how to change your code and still achieve what you want..

**EDIT:**

Your comment:

> Number 2 sounds like what I want. I need the String to parse through it to create objects that will be added to an ArrayList. I then want to add the list to an Intent and send the Intent off to the next activity on a button click.

Here is how you can achieve what you want. Basically, you have to put all your code that you want to be executed after you receive the result in a separate method.

First of all, the easiest way of sending objects between activities is to make them `public static` so that both activities can access them and use them. The other ways are to make your objects [**`Serializable`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) or [**`Parceable`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). [**Here's what they are and what's the difference**](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/).

Inside your activity put:

```
public static ArrayList<MyObject> myList;
```

Then in the activity you want to call you can access this like:

```
YOUR_ACTIVITY.myList
```

When you add an `OnClickListener` to your button, make sure it doesn't do anything until you receive the data. You can achieve this with a `boolean` flag.

```
boolean isDataReceived = false;
// ...
public void onClick() {
    if(isDataReceived) {
    // create a new intent and start your other activity
    } 
}
```

The method you should create is:

```
void onReceiveResult(String result) {
    // parse the string and store it in myList
    isDataReceived = true;
}
```

And you should call it from `onPostExecute()`

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
   onReceiveResult(result);
}
```

This way, as soon as you receive data, you can parse it, store it and set the flag that tells data is stored. Then you can call the other activity on button clicks.

**NOTE:** Make sure to set the `isDataReceived` back to `false` each time you are changing the list or deleting it.

Comment: I think this is going in the right direction but the way I am calling it, I am getting a null value in the String in `onCreate()`.  As I have it, `DataTransfer()` is not in the `GetDataTask()` class. In doing this, I had to also add static to the class so the variable could be static.

Comment: Number 2 sounds like what I want.  I need the `String` to parse through it to create objects that will be added to an `ArrayList`. I then want to add the list to an `Intent` and send the `Intent` off to the next activity on a button click.

Comment: This is going to work perfectly!  Thanks!  Now I pose this question. Is there a better way to do something like this from the beginning so I will know better for next time?

Comment: @WeVie you are welcome. Well not really, always learn from your mistakes is all I can say. The more you code the better you will get so just remember what you did wrong now for next time :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you need to return your result in onCreate. To accomplish this you can use [get](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) function in AsyncTask to get result synchroniously, but you will block your interface than and I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a 'Getter' function to receive the 'String'. Or a function you create with a return value in class 'GetDataTask'.